# $('select').click(function() not work properly

Tags: jquery, html

plase look at link below

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEfft/5/)

in above link when i click on select tag using mouse click, at first time click it will not expand option value.

```
    $('select').click(function(){
        $(this).attr("size",1); 
        var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";       
        $(x).fadeTo('fast',1.0);            
    });
```

this function on which onclick event fire,this function create the problem but i want this function to select option from option list.

please show me any possible way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$('select').change()` instead of `$('select').click()`. Click is not event for `select`.

According to your comment I think you need something like ***[this](http://jsfiddle.net/jEfft/8/)***

```
$('select option').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().attr("size", 1);
    $(this).parent().val(this.value);
    var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).parent().attr('tabindex'), 10) + 1) + "']";
    $(x).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
});
```

Comment: `$('select').change()` not allow me to view option list using up down arrow key.

Comment: @win Please see my above demo

Comment: `@thecodeparadox` your edited code work fine for me..thanks a lot